# Golang date parsing malfunction

Tags: date, parsing, go

I'm trying to parse a user-input date string in the form yyyy-mm-dd (with nothing else behind) so that I can write it the same way into a file (again with nothing else behind).
However the user input is not read correctly and I don't know why. Any hint would be great.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var datestring string
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Startdatum im Format yyyy-mm-dd eingeben (z.B. 2018-06-24):\n")
    datestring, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T, Value: %v", datestring, datestring)

    t1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", datestring)   //0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
    t2, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2018-05-27") //2018-05-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
    fmt.Printf("%v\n%v\n", t1, t2)

}
```

Comment: For one time.Parse returns an object of type time.Time, whose String() interface{} is predefined to print out the time value in a very specific way. If you want it to print out the time again in the way it was ingested then you have to format yourself again. eg. `fmt.Println(t1.Format("2006-01-02"))`

Comment: Never, literally never ever emit error checking. The errors are there for good reason and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: :facepalm: Don't ignore errors!

Comment: Thanks, guys, very instructive! The t1.Format command also helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read `datestring`, it has a line feed (`\n`) termination character at the end. `time.Parse()` reads this as a parse error since it's not in your format string so you will need to handle this.

One way is to strip it off with `strings.TrimSpace()` as follow:

```
datestring, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
datestring = strings.TrimSpace(datestring)
```

You can alternately add a `\n` to your string format, but trimming the line feed would be my preference since it uses a more standard time format string.

```
t1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02\n", datestring)
```

To debug this, you should handle the error from `time.Parse()` like so:

```
t1, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", datestring) //0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will return the following error indicating there is additional text in your string. Note the closing double quote `"` does not immediately follow the date.

```
panic: parsing time "2018-06-24
": extra text: 


goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /path/to/main.go:19 +0x503
exit status 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brillant explanation - great pleasure to read! I again read the golang doc on ReadString and found: "ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter." The latter I did not expect but now I know.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this solution:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // User date input
    var datestring string
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Input start date in format yyyy-mm-dd (e.g. 2018-06-24):\n")
    datestring, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    datestring = strings.TrimSpace(datestring)

    // Formatted date output
    t1, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", datestring) //0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
    t2 := t1.Format("2006-01-02")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", t2)
}
```